# How to match a regex with backreference in Go?

Tags: regex, go, backreference

I need to match a regex that uses backreferences (e.g. \1) in my Go code.

That's not so easy because in Go, the [official regexp package](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) uses the [RE2 engine](http://code.google.com/p/re2/), one that have [chosen to not support backreferences](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html) (and some other lesser-known features) so that there can be a guarantee of linear-time execution, therefore avoiding [regex denial-of-service attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS). Enabling backreferences support is not an option with RE2.

In my code, there is no risk of malicious exploitation by attackers, and I need backreferences.

What should I do?

Comment: are you sure you *need* to have this fancy regex? what are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 13):

Answering my own question here, I solved this using [golang-pkg-pcre](https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre), it uses libpcre++, perl regexes that do support backreferences. The API is [not the same](https://godoc.org/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre).

Comment: This is great, because I need bug-for-bug compatibility with an existing system.

Comment: Would you please post an example?  I found that package, couldn't get backreferencing to work, then found an issue on its tracker indicating that others couldn't either.

Comment: @ESR I found my old code from 2014, it still works. Even your sample code runs fine. https://gist.github.com/eldritchconundrum/790680bec2a4ce34b6d7a346d239e3a5

Comment: @esr oh wait, you meant backreferences in the replacement string... No, they don't appear to work. I only needed backreferences in the pattern string, so I didn't notice.

Comment: for those curious, the bug @ESR was referring to is:
https://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/issues/8

Answer (score 10):

Regular Expressions are great for working with regular grammars, but if your grammar isn't regular (i.e. requires back-references and stuff like that) you should probably switch to a better tool. There are a lot of good tools available for parsing context-free grammars, including [yacc](http://golang.org/cmd/yacc/) which is shipped with the Go distribution by default. Alternatively, you can also write your own parser. [Recursive descent parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) can be easily written by hand for example.

I think regular expressions are overused in scripting languages (like Perl, Python, Ruby, ...) because their C/ASM powered implementation is usually more optimized than those languages itself, but Go isn't such a language. Regular expressions are usually quite slow and are often not suited for the problem at all.

Comment: Regexps have legitimate uses even for non-regular grammars.  I agree that regexps for parsing is often a poor choice, but not all regexes are used for parsing, e.g. regex search in your favorite text editor.  In my case, I'd have no use for a custom parser, I really need a regex, it's the spec.

Comment: regular expressions don't match non-regular grammars.

Comment: @tomwilde - Sure they do. The engines in modern regex tools haven't been "[REGULAR](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html#comment_40 "See this comment written by the author of the Perl camel book")" for some decades now.

Comment: @ridgerunner That's why they are called *extended* regular expressions.

Comment: @fuz not by anyone who knows what they're talking about. That causes confusion with POSIX ERE (which, ironically, is not very "extended" and doesn't even support backreference).

Answer (score 3):

When I had the same problem, I solved it using a two-step regular expression match. The original code is:

```
if m := match(pkgname, `^(.*)\$\{DISTNAME:S(.)(\\^?)([^:]*)(\\$?)\2([^:]*)\2(g?)\}(.*)$`); m != nil {
    before, _, left, from, right, to, mod, after := m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4], m[5], m[6], m[7], m[8]
    // ...
}
```

The code is supposed to parse a string of the form `${DISTNAME:S|from|to|g}`, which itself is a little pattern language using the familiar substitution syntax `S|replace|with|`.

The two-stage code looks like this:

```
if m, before, sep, subst, after := match4(pkgname, `^(.*)\$\{DISTNAME:S(.)([^\\}:]+)\}(.*)$`); m {
    qsep := regexp.QuoteMeta(sep)
    if m, left, from, right, to, mod := match5(subst, `^(\^?)([^:]*)(\$?)`+qsep+`([^:]*)`+qsep+`(g?)$`); m {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `match`, `match4` and `match5` are my own wrapper around the `regexp` package, and they cache the compiled regular expressions so that at least the compilation time is not wasted.

Answer (score 1):

regexp package funcs [FindSubmatchIndex](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllSubmatchIndex) and [Expand](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Expand) can capture content by backreferences. It isn't very convenient, but it is still possible. [Example](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#example-Regexp.Expand)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    content := []byte(`
    # comment line
    option1: value1
    option2: value2

    # another comment line
    option3: value3
`)

    pattern := regexp.MustCompile(`(?m)(?P<key>\w+):\s+(?P<value>\w+)$`)

    template := []byte("$key=$value\n")
    result := []byte{}
    for _, submatches := range pattern.FindAllSubmatchIndex(content, -1) {
        result = pattern.Expand(result, template, content, submatches)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(result))
}
```

output

```
option1=value1
option2=value2
option3=value3
```

Comment: The question is about something else, but I was looking for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was an old question, but I haven't found a simple solution from answers above.

In addition, "golang-pkg-pcre" does not work on macOS with M1.

Therefore, I would like to contribute my idea.

For example, to replace <u> or <I> with <b> and replace </u> or </I> with </b>.  The search is case-insensitive.

Let me compare how to do it in python and in go

In python, it is easy as below:

```
import re
content = "<u>test1</u> <i>test2</i>\n<U>test3</U> <I>test4</I>"
content = re.sub(r"<(u|i)>([^<>]+?)</\1>", r"<b>\2</b>", content, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(content)
```

In go, I do it this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    content := "<u>test1</u> <i>test2</i>\n<U>test3</U> <I>test4</I>"
    content = changeUITagToBTag(content)
    fmt.Println(content)
}

// change <u> or <i> to <b> and </u> or </i> to </b>
// case-insensitive search
func changeUITagToBTag(content string) string {
    pattern := `<(u|i)>([^<>]+?)</(u|i)>`
    compiledPattern := regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf(`(?%v)%v`, "i", pattern))
    content = compiledPattern.ReplaceAllStringFunc(content, func(text string) string {
        allSubStrings := compiledPattern.FindAllStringSubmatch(text, -1)
        if allSubStrings[0][1] == allSubStrings[0][3] {
            return fmt.Sprintf(`<b>%s</b>`, allSubStrings[0][2])
        }
        return text
    })
    return content
}
```