# How to use lookbehind regexp in go?

Tags: ruby, regex, go

I'm trying to convert this ruby regex to go.

```
GROUP_CALL = /^(?<i1>[ \t]*)group\(?[ \t]*(?<grps>#{SYMBOLS})[ \t]*\)?[ \t]+do[ \t]*?\n(?<blk>.*?)\n^\k<i1>end[ \t]*$/m
```

I converted it to

```
groupCall := regexp.MustCompile("^(?P<i1>[ \\t]*)group\\(?[ \\t]*(?P<grps>(?::\\w+|:\"[^\"#]+\"|:'[^']+')([ \\t]*,[ \\t]*(?::\\w+|:\"[^\"#]+\"|:'[^']+'))*)[ \\t]*\\)?[ \\t]+do[ \\t]*?\\n(?P<blk>.*?)\\n^\\k<i1>end[ \\t]*$/s")
```

but when run I get this error

```
error parsing regexp: invalid escape sequence: \k
```

There's no mention of `\k` in the [go docs](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/), is there no equivalent in go?

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23968993/3832970). In short: it is not possible to use backreferences in Go regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lookbehinds aren't supported neither are backreferences like **@stribizhev** mentioned.

**Regular Expression 2 (RE2) Syntax Reference:**
https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

> The syntax of the regular expressions accepted is the same general
>   syntax used by Perl, Python, and other languages. More precisely, it
>   is the syntax accepted by RE2 and described at
>   //code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax, except for \C. **--GoLang Docs**
>   (**ref:** https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/)