# Forcing regex to match exactly optional group at the start and the end of the regex

Tags: regex, go

How to force regex to match for optional groups at the beginning and the end of the regex. Example:

`(keyword1)*\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword2)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword3)*`

Here keyword1 and keywrod3 are at the start and the end of the regex respectively and are optional. I am looking for keyword1, keyword2 and keyword3 in this order.We can have up to 6 words between keywords but the matched string should start by one keyword and end by one of the keywords. No extra string is needed. Is there a way to do that. Any suggestion is welcome. Here is a code and a link to [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/h5mXISPCk8):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    //here ok as exact match. The matched string starts by one of the keyword and ends by one of them. 
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(keyword1)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword2)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword3)`)
    text := "start text keyword1 optional word here then keyword2 again optional words then keyword3 others words after."
        s := re.FindAllString(text, -1)
    fmt.Println(s)

    //Here not exact match as the result doesn't start by keyword1 and end by keyword3
    re = regexp.MustCompile(`(keyword1)*\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword2)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword3)*`)
    text = "start text keyword1 optional word then keyword2 optional words keyword3 others words after."
    s = re.FindAllString(text, -1)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is impossible to achieve with 1 Go regex. You will have to use `(keyword1)*\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword2)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword3)*` and then add more programming logic.

Comment: You mean adding programming logic to remove extra strings?

Comment: Something should be added to perform additional checks. Another way is to make the `keyword1` and `keyword3` obligatory in 2 alternatives, `(keyword1)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword2)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword3)*|(keyword1)*\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword2)\W*(?:\w+\W+){0,6}(keyword3)`, but still it will require "manual" work later.

Comment: Someone had the pretty same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968992/how-to-match-a-regex-with-backreference-in-go
Because you need to use backreferences for that.