# how to reference group with golang regex

Tags: regex, go

I want to match some repeated number like 1111, but '\1' is  invalid escape sequence in golang. How to do that?

```
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d)\1{3}`)
```

Comment: Why do you want to escape the `1`?

Comment: I want to reference the group (\d), '\1' can work with python and cpp. How to do in golang?

Comment: Hi!
I think this could be helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968992/how-to-match-a-regex-with-backreference-in-go

Answer (score 1):

golang's RE2 engine does not support backreferences.