# How to check if a string contain 2 same char in a row?

Tags: regex, go, syntax

I have a regex like this

```
REGEX_2_SAME_CHARACTER_IN_A_ROW = "^(?:(.)(?!\\1\\1))*$"
```

and check password with that regex if it contain 2 same character in a row

```
contain2SameCharacterInARow, err := regexp.MatchString(REGEX_2_SAME_CHARACTER_IN_A_ROW, password)
```

but I get this error

```
error match regex 2 same char in a row: error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`
```

I have read other question that using regexp.MustCompile but I don't know how to handle or code it, is there anyone can help me with the solution?

Here you can check my full code for validate password
https://play.golang.com/p/5Fj4-UPvL8s

Comment: I think you're just looking for `(.)\\1`

Comment: Some things should not be done with a regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the anchor, the non-capturing group, nor the negative lookahead. Simply match and capture any character (`(.)`) followed by itself (`\\1`).

```
REGEX_2_SAME_CHARACTER_IN_A_ROW = "(.)\\1"
```

But this brings us to the next problem: [Go regexes do not support back references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968992/how-to-match-a-regex-with-backreference-in-go), so you need to find a different solution. One would be looping the string yourself.

Here's a solution with a simple loop:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(ValidatePassword("passsword01"))
}

func ContainsRepeatedChar(s string) bool {
    chars := strings.Split(s, "")
    char := chars[0]
    for i := 1; i < len(chars); i++ {
        if (chars[i] == char) {
            return true
        }
        char = chars[i]
    }
    return false
}

func ValidatePassword(password string) error {
    contain2SameCharacterInARow := ContainsRepeatedChar(password)
    if contain2SameCharacterInARow {
        fmt.Println("duplicated char")
        return errors.New("invalid password")
    }

    fmt.Println("all good")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: it is work for me, just need to escape the backslash. REGEX_2_SAME_CHARACTER_IN_A_ROW = "(.)\\\\1"

Comment: @MohammadGhifariYusuf that regex will match anything followed by two back slashes, followed by the digit 1.